# Finding basis of the given Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Find the nullity and a basis of the null space of the linear transformation $A:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ given by$$
> A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 0&1&-3&-1\\1&0&1&1\\3&1&0&2\\1&1&-2&0\end{pmatrix}.
> $$

Do I first convert the matrix into a linear transformation (a method that is very time consuming and tedious) and then find the null space?

Or is there a quicker method?

Comment: You need to solve the equation $AX=0$ to begin with.  If the only solution is the $0$ vector then the nullity is $0$ and the basis is empty.  If there is more than one solution, then the general solution will be expressed in terms of a number of parameters.  Something like $$X=t_1X_1+\dots+t_kX_k$$  Then $k$ will be the nullity, and $X_1,\dots ,X_k$ the basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just solve the linear system $Ax=0$ using elementary row operations.

Find the nullity and a basis of the solution space.

Comment: What is the basis of this procedure?

Comment: The linear transformation is defined as $T(x)=Ax$ right? Hence the question of finding the solution of $T(x)=0$ is equivalent to the problem of $Ax=0$.

Comment: Isn't A the matrix of T (the two basis thing)?

Comment: I am referring to [linear transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearTransformation.html) where $T(v)=Av$.

Comment: The original question said that "A was the matrix of T" - doesn't that mean, that when T is represented as a matrix (where columns are co-ordinates) then we get A?

Comment: The $i$-th columns of $A$ are indeed the image of $T(e_i)$ where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard unit basis. Given that the transformation  is linear, it is equivalent  to $T(x)=Ax$.

Comment: So let us say I am given two basis B1, B2 of R3. 
Then I say that the Linear transformation T is REPRESENTED by the matrix A.

What does this mean?
(a) [T:B1;B2] = A
(b) T(X) = AX
(c) Are both the statements above equivalent? I THINK that's the case for the standard basis, if I am not wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $[T:B_1; B_2]$, but given two basis, we construct $A$ as follows. We take the $j$-th element of $B_1$, call it $u_j$, compute $T(u_j)$, express it as linear combination of elements of $B_2$ and record down the coefficients as the element $A_j$.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what [T:B1;B2] means, I am asking is it the same as T(X) = AX? I mean is it true for any non standard basis too?

Comment: Yes, that is the corresponding $A$. Here your $B_1$ and $B_2$ are the standard unit basis.

Comment: And what if B1 and B2 are non-standard basis then?

Comment: Then your $A$ could looks different.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and let $N_{A} = \left \{ \mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{n} : A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0} \right \}$.

The span of the vectors in $N_{A}$ is the kernel of matrix $A$, denoted as $ker(A)$, and $dim(N_{A})$ is the nullity of $A$. If $N_{A}$ contains only the zero vector, then $nullity(A) = 0$.

For the basis, reduce the matrix to row echelon form (not reduced). The non-zero rows form a basis.